# Value lookup with VBA and not SQL?

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

Is it possible to replicate this with just VBA instead of using SQL?

```
txtSCDate.Value = "SELECT [SC Date] FROM [Stock Conversion] WHERE [SCID] = " & txtSCNumber.Value & ";"
```

If not then how do you run that SQL from the VBA?

Thanks in advance,
Bob P

Comment: I realise that this is not your design, but where possible, get rid of spaces in fields (columns) and table names. It will mean you can cut down a lot on square brackets, which are only required when there is a space, a special character or a reserved word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DLookUp:

```
txtSCDate.Value = DlookUp("[SC Date]","[Stock Conversion]","SCID = " _
                & txtSCNumber.Value)
```

Note that you can set the control source of a textbox to a domain function such as DLookUp.

If you wanted to use SQL, then:

```
Dim rs As Recordset

sSQL = "SELECT [SC Date] FROM [Stock Conversion] WHERE SCID = " _
     & txtSCNumber.Value
Set rs = CurrentDB.Openrecordset(sSQL)
Me.txtSCNumber = rs![SC date]
```